# JSONP response is getting trucated

Tags: jquery, web-services, browser, cross-platform, jsonp

I am trying to consume JSONP response in cross platform. I am using HTML and JQuery Mobile. Sometimes when there are more no of records the response automatically get truncated after fixed no of charcters, doesnt read complete response as in JSON format. I couldnt get the complete response.
However the same response working fine for JSON and can be easily consumed in Android.

In cross platform app, on browser when I checked it get trucated, anyone have idea on this?
It would be really appreciable, if anyone can help on this

**UPDATE**

On Apache Tomcat it is working fine, but for JBOSS Application Server I am facing the issue.
Can maxHttpHeaderSize be a issue. Pls tell me what really maxHttpHeaderSize has effect on this..?

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Please read my question once more, I dont think code will help you.
I am using normal ajax call and works fine for less no of characters but when no of characters are large then it is being truncated because of that I am not getting correct response

Comment: when it works how many records do you get back? When it doesn't work, how many records did you get back? When it doesn't work how many records did you expect to get back? How long is the request taking when it does and doesn't work? I think code would definitely help. I searched google for 'jquery ajax size limit' and got some interesting leads.

Comment: might be depending on the device itself, like on the server side (for example php's max post size), the response might have a maximum length to be read...would it be possible to spilt the response into parts?

Comment: Is the service .NET?  JavaScriptSerializer has a param that limits the json length.  It can increased like this: myserializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

Comment: @ajitksharma check something please, confirm that your JSON is being parsed correctly, try to receive it in you jquery as pure text! and check that it is arriving entirely at  your browser. can happen that you have some error in the middle of your JSON and jquery is just spitting an malformed json! It's just an hint, let me know if it helped you.

Comment: @JoãoPinho: It is being parsed correctly, it is happening wth all responses. As number of characters exceeding it get truncate otherwise its working fine...

Comment: @SQLDBA: Its in Java. I am using Apache Axis2 and Jax RS for JSONP

Answer (score 4):

JSON can be handled via POST request, JSONP is always GET, and most webservers limit the length of a GET request to  8192 bytes (8KB)

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: When I encountered it, I had to change the logic of my app to split the data that it sent to the server into separate, smaller requests, as I didn't have access to the service host to change the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the accepted answer correctly describes your problem, as your problem is with the response and the size limits are usually with the request url length...  There are many web pages on the web which are bigger than 8kb and they get sent back just fine.

I had a problem which looked similar:  I was using tomcat behind nginex and apparently nginex was chopping the response to several parts after about 64kb.  As it seemed jquery does not know how to handle multi-part responses (it might go deeper than jquery I'm not sure).  When I did the same locally using Tomcat w/o nginex with the same data it worked perfectly so perhaps the magic number in Tomcat is different.

In order to bypass the problem (didn't find a way to solve it), I had to limit the amount of elements asked for by the query, and keep asking until I get all elements (so ask for 0-99, then 100-199, etc. until I get less than 100 records), so that the magic number of bytes returned won't trigger the chop mechanism.